# Is there a way to get the last filled row cell value from column using OpenXml

Tags: c#, console-application, openxml

I am working on a Console application that simply grabs the value from a specified cell and displays that value to the Console. I would like to modify the code and get the value of the last cell's value in a column. I am able to get the value of cells I specify but I wish to only get the last filled cell(because the addressName may change when the sheet is updated with more rows ). I am currently using the code below to get the values by addressName. Can someone point me in the right direction or show an example. please and thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Temp\myTempDoc\bigexcel.xlsx";
        string sheetName = "sheet1";
        string addressName = "B25";
        var cellVall =GetCellValue(fileName, sheetName, addressName);
        Console.WriteLine(cellVall);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static string GetCellValue(string fileName,string sheetName,string addressName)
    {
        string value = null;
        // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document =
            SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
            // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
            Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
              Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();
            // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
            if (theSheet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
            }
            // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
            WorksheetPart wsPart =
                (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));
            // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
            // whose address matches the address you supplied.
            Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
              Where(c => c.CellReference ==addressName ).FirstOrDefault();
            // If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
            if (theCell != null)
            {
                value = theCell.InnerText;
                // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
                // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
                // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
                // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
                // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
                // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
                // the words TRUE or FALSE.
                if (theCell.DataType != null)
                {
                    switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                    {
                        case CellValues.SharedString:

                            // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                            // shared strings table.
                            var stringTable =
                                wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                            // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                            // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                            // the table.
                            if (stringTable != null)
                            {
                                value =
                                    stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                    .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                            }
                            break;
                        case CellValues.Boolean:
                            switch (value)
                            {
                                case "0":
                                    value = "FALSE";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    value = "TRUE";
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear whether you are after the last `Cell` in a `Row` of your choosing or the last `Cell` of the last `Row`. Both approaches are very similar though so I'll show how to do both.

The basic principal is to find the `Row` you are after first and then to grab the child `Cell`s from that `Row`.

If you want the very last `Cell` of the sheet then we just want the last `Row`:

```
//grab the last row
Row row = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().LastOrDefault();
```

However, if you would like to be able to pass in a row number and grab the last `Cell` of that `Row` then something like this will do the trick (here the variable `rowIndex` denotes the index of the `Row` for which you want the last `Cell`):

```
//find the row that matches the rowNumber we're after
Row row = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>()
                          .Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).FirstOrDefault();
```

Once you have the `Row`, it's just a case of grabbing the last `Cell` of that `Row` using similar code to the above:

```
Cell theCell = null;

//find the row that matches the rowNumber we're after
Row row = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).FirstOrDefault();

if (row != null)
{
    //now grab the last cell of that row
    theCell = row.Descendants<Cell>().LastOrDefault();
}

// If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
if (theCell != null)
...
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot in two ways. First it helped me realize my question was not clear .two it help me period; I wanted to know the last row so I could cell values from it .

Comment: Glad I could help @OlujideOluade. If my answer answers your question, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That's completely optional though. If it doesn't answer it and you need more information just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue and I found that an empty row of excel (OpenXml) has descendants = 1:

```
                while(++rowIndex < rows.Count())
                {
                    currentRow = rows.ElementAt(rowIndex);
                    int descendants = currentRow.Descendants<Cell>().Count();
                    if(descendants <= 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // your code   
                }
```

, so you can  continue to read the rows and ignore empty rows until the last row.